# Recursive equation of following code snippet

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computer-science

### Question

> consider the following code snippet

```
A(n)
{
  if (n<1) return 1;
  else return A(n-2)+B(n-1)
}

B(n)
{
  if(n<=1) 
  return 1;
  else return B(n-1)+A(n-2)
}
```

find $A(6)$

### My Approach & query

Its easy to calculate $A(6)$,it is coming as $16$.But i want to solve it using finding its recursive equation so that i can find $A(n)$ for any value of $n$.

I started as-:

> $$A(n)=A(n-2)+B(n-1)$$
> $$=A(n-2)+B(n-2)+A(n-3)$$
> $$   =A(n-2)+A(n-3) +B(n-2)$$
> But seriously i am hopeless to go further .please help me out to solve such type of question.

thanks

Comment: If we compute the first terms of $A(n)$ numerically we can look it up in the OEIS and find https://oeis.org/A055389 . If we do the same for $B(n)$ we find
https://oeis.org/A163733 (but need to define an offset 0 then....)

Comment: The two recurrences look very similar. Maybe $A(n)=B(n)$? Did you calculate the first few values of the sequences? What did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the recursive definition, you have to start from the beginning, that is $A(-1) = A(0) = 1$, $B(0) = 1$ and $B(1) = 1$. 
Moreover, for $n \geqslant 2$, you get 
$$
A(n) = A(n-2) + B(n-1) = B(n-1) + A(n-2) = B(n)
$$
Therefore, for $n \geqslant 3$, one gets $B(n-1) = A(n-1)$, whence
$$
A(n) = A(n-2) + A(n-1)
$$
Thus $A(n)$ is a Fibonacci type sequence: 
$$
A(0) = 1 \quad A(1) = 2 \quad A(3)= 4 \quad A(4) = 6 \quad A(5) = 10 \quad A(6) = 16  \quad \dotsm
$$